# Iframe redirect losing session information in IE10 and IE11

Tags: javascript, php, iframe

I have implemented a payment gateway using an iframe.

Before they are sent to the iframe, i store a url in the session that I want the user to go to next. After the user has finished and they submit, this iframe goes to a 'redirect' page that i've set up which basically a javascript page which runs top.location.href and breaks out of the iframe... it then continues to the url set in the session.

In IE10 and 11 this session is not available and therefore I have no where I can send the user. If I turn the privacy to 'Allow All Cookies' it works fine, but obviously that is not a solution.

Anyone have any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: In order to get this working in the short/long term. I put the session data into memcached then on return I am checking if it is available and if not it pulls the data out of memcached and recreates the session. This works but if there are better methods them I'm happy to switch.